# Finding whether function values are dependent or independent?

Tags: probability, independence

For the following question, I do not know what to do because I have only used dependence and independence on numbers, not functions.

Two numbers are drawn at random from the set $ \{1,2,3,4\}$

If order is not important, what is the sample space $S$? 
$S = \text{All combinations of} \{1,2,3,4\}$

Define the following functions on $S$:

$X(\{i,j\}) = i + j $

$Y(\{i,j\}) = |i-j| $

Which of the following pairs of events are independent?

(1) $ X = 5$ and $Y = 2, $

(2) $X = 5$ and $Y = 1$

The only thing i could think of is taking two numbers out of the set and making the function equal to X or Y using them, but even then, I don't know how to approach it.

Comment: Your sample space is actually the set of all ${4 \choose 2}$ pairs of numbers in $\{1,2,3,4\}$.  I assume that all pairs are supposed to be equally likely. The event $\{X=5\}\cap\{Y=2\}$ means that the sum of the numbers is 5, and the difference is 2.  Can you answer for which pairs does this work?

Comment: Of course, I am assuming the two numbers drawn are distinct (i.e., "sampling without replacement").  After reading your description again, it is not clear to me whether or not the two numbers drawn are allowed to be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A start: To find out whether the events $X=a$ and $Y=b$ are independent, do this:

(1) Calculate $\Pr(X=a)$, $\Pr(Y=b)$ and $\Pr(X=a\cap Y=b)$.

(2) If $\Pr(X=a\cap Y=b)=\Pr(X=a)\Pr(Y=b)$ then the events are independent. Otherwise, they are not independent.

Note that we do not always really need to do a detailed computation. For example, $\Pr(X=5)\ne 0$ and $\Pr(Y=2)\ne 0$. But $\Pr(X=5\cap Y=2)=0$, since we cannot have $i+j$ odd and $|i-j|$ even.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you for answering another one of my questions!

Comment: You are welcome.